# Python output formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a question from a paid course by Ardit Sulce:

Fill in two {} brackets so that output of the code is "Welcome A.S to our shop!"

```
firstname = "Andy"
lastname = "Smith"
print("Welcome {}.{} to our shop!".format(firstname, lastname))
```

My solution was

```
print("Welcome {0[0]}.{1[0]} to our shop!".format(firstname, lastname))
```

But the author's solution is:

```
print("Welcome {:.1}.{:.1} to our shop!".format(firstname, lastname))
```

Both solutions work.The one by author looks very cute, but I do not understand.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the syntax, but it looks like it's selecting up to (non inclusively) the index `1`. This article may help: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Comment: this also works: `print("Welcome {}.{} to our shop!".format(firstname[0], lastname[0]))`, or using f-strings: `print(f"Welcome {firstname[0]}.{lastname[0]} to our shop!")`

Comment: Note that the author's solution will *not* raise an index error in the event that either `firstname` or `lastname` are zero-length strings.

Comment: This may help `Advanced String Formatting` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: @ArvindDhakad thanks for PEP-3101 reference, that is pure gold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author's solution uses the format mini-language's definition of "precision" for strings. With floating-point values, it is the expected number of digits.

```
>>> "{:.1}".format(3.14159)
'3e+00'
>>> "{:.2}".format(3.14159)
'3.1'
```

For strings, it's the maximum field width.

```
>>> "{:.1}".format("foo")
'f'
>>> "{:.2}".format("foo")
'fo'
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'. **For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content.** The precision is not allowed for integer values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is cuter:

```
print("Welcome {[0]}.{[0]} to our shop!".format(firstname, lastname))
```

You don't need the 0 and 1, Python knows that inside the {}, you are referring to the first and second arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To add to chepner's answer, if you scroll down on his documentation link, to [Format Examples](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-examples), you'll find the explanation of the colon as well.

> In most of the cases the syntax is similar to the old %-formatting, with the addition of the {} and with : used instead of %. For example, '%03.2f' can be translated to '{:03.2f}'.

You'll also see that `{} {}` is equivalent to `{0}, {1}` (i.e. implied position).